# What is the name of the heroine in Amnesia?

Tags: amnesia

Okay, So I haven't played the latest otome game of Amnesia yet because it hasn't come out which is Amnesia- World yet and I am not sure whether I will be able to get a PC version of it and the anime stopped with the heroine actually returning back to her own world, so it didn't quite cover as much as it did in the game.

There is however one element throughout the anime and the games so far that remained the same, her name.

So what is her name? Is she known as anything else other than "heroine"?

Comment: I can't say anything about whether Amnesia World gives her a name, but at least at the beginning she's still unnamed. See [the official website for the VN](http://www.otomate.jp/amnesia/world/#/chara). Her profile from that says (translated by me): "A female college student who lost her memories and personality. She's trying to find the clues to her past in the people around her."

Answer (score 1):

She is only known as "Heroine." Now, if you look at Wikipedia or any other source and check the dates, you'll see that the anime is released after the game.

If the developers of the game never named her, e.g. implying the "Heroine" is whomever plays as her in the game, they didn't need to name her. This would allow the players to insert themselves into the game as the game's "Heroine."

So the fact that she isn't named could be entirely intentional in the game and the decision was carried over to the anime. If she didn't need a name in the game, I guess she didn't need it in the anime.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amnesia_(visual_novel)

Comment: For what it's worth, there is an in-universe reason why she doesn't have a name. She forgot it, along with basically everything else, hence the name "Amnesia". However, I agree that they were probably also trying to use this as a way to let the player insert themselves more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think she has any name other than HEROINE in the anime and the Game.[image]

Comment: I assume you mean to say "heroine" and not "heroin"? I don't know anything about Amnesia so I can't tell if it's a typo or not.

Comment: @Maroon yeh it is a typo, Logan M's link and the [VNDB Page](http://vndb.org/v7803/chars#chars) both have an e at the end